# Http connection interruption detection

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest, servlets

Let's imagine a web client makes an HTTP request to a server.

I need a way to know if the client closed the connection while the server was processing it's request.

I understand that there is 499 status code (Client closed request) but from what I've seen it's intended for request's to Nginx web server.

I'm using Websphere Application Server, and followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302072/how-can-i-get-the-http-status-code-out-of-a-servletresponse-in-a-servletfilter) to get the status code:

Comment: Can you describe your setup a little more? Are you running nginx as a proxy to your application? And what does the architecture look like behind nginx? If you have something like a load balancer -> nginx -> web app it could be tricky